# range operator in if statement goes in infinite loop

Tags: perl

I am trying to use range operator in if statement to print something whenever value of $b is between 1 and 3 but the below code goes into infinite loop.
I am not sure about how range operator in if statement is working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
for ($b = 0; $b < 10; $b++) {
    if ($b = 1 .. 3) {
        print "test\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't mention the warnings that generates.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. one more thing if i have two conditions on left side of the ".." , then how will it work i.e.                   #!/usr/bin/perl
##use warnings;
while(<>){
if(($c = 1 and $b=3)..not$b--)
{
print "the values of c and b is $c and $b\n";
}
}                                                                           what will be range of "if()"?

Comment: if either operand to .. is a constant, it is treated as if you said `$.==` that constant, so is checking the line number.  if an operand is any other expression, that expression is evaluated as a boolean.  so your example would not depend on line numbers at all.  note that ($c=1 and $b=3) is always true; did you mean == not =?

Answer (score 6):

A [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) does not work the way you're trying to use it.  Your `if` is equivalent to the following:

```
if ( $b = ($. == 1) .. ($. == 3) ) {
```

Because you're not doing any file operations, `$.` will be undefined.  Therefore, the range will always throw a warning and fail and assign undef to `$b`.  Then because `$b` is being assigned a value, the `for` loop will never exit.

You need to use [simple comparators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

for ( $b = 0; $b < 10; $b++ ) {
    if ( $b >= 1 && $b <= 3 ) {
        print "test\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
test
test
test
```

Comment: You're right of course ...  I confused myself, briefly.  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

`..` in scalar context is not the range operator, it is the flipflop operator.  You would use it appropriately like this:

```
while ( my $line = readline $filehandle ) {
    # print only first three lines
    if ( 1..3 ) {
        print "line $.: $line\n";
    }
}
```

The flipflop returns false until the first condition (constants being treated implicitly as needing to be compared to $., the current line number) returns true.  Then it continues returning true until the second condition is true.  So in the example above, the if block is only entered for lines 1 through 3 of the input.

The infinite loop is because you are assigning '' to $b each time through the loop; perhaps you meant `==` (comparison), not `=` (assignment).  But even that won't work with a range the way you are attempting.

If you want to check if a number is in a given range, don't use either the range operator or flipflop operator; just compare:

```
if ( $b >= 1 && $b <= 3 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your `if` condition

You are using

```
if($b = 1..3){
```

As it is going inside `if` condition it is assigning value 1 to `$b` so every time its value will remain 1 that is way it is moving in infinite loop.

for making this loop to work within range `1..3` you can use

`if($b == 1 || $b == 2 ||$b == 3)` or `if($b >= 1 && $b <= 3)`

Comment: `$b == 1..3` doesn't do anything vaguely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to print "test" if $b is equal to 1 or 2 or 3. Your code would give "Use of uninitialized value in range (or flop) at test.pl line 6." and instead of 3 times it will print 10 times.

Suggested code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for (my $b = 0; $b<10; $b++){
  if($b =~ /[1-3]/){
    print "test\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: you need anchors on that: `/^[1-3]\z/`; otherwise any number that has a 1, 2, or 3 anywhere in it will match too.

Comment: Yes, true. He had 1 to 10 hard coded and <10 so i didn't mention. But yours one is generic :D

Answer (score 0):

@Miller response is great, and it suits your needs. If you are looking for a method of search if a value is contained into an array (numeric or non numeric, non sequential values, etc.), take a look to the [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) CPAN module.

This example looks for the value 5 into an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/any/;

my @range = (1 .. 100);
my $search_for = 5;
my $found_in_range = any { $_ == $search_for } @range;
print $found_in_range, "\n";  #<-- prints: 1
```